# Check if value is greater than a different value having weird results

Tags: android, if-statement

I am currently working on android project, and I am not sure if I am just really tired and done something stupid but something doesn't make any sense to me. I have the following code:

```
long pauseTime = settings.getLong("timePaused", 0);
        long currentTime = common.getCurrentEpochTimeStamp();
        int difference = (int) (currentTime - pauseTime);
        int secondsBeforeLogOff = settings.getInt("autoLogOffTime", 10) * 60;
        if (secondsBeforeLogOff > difference)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
```

When I debug and step through the code above the `secondsBeforeLogOff` is set to 60 and the `difference` is 5. In the if statement I would expect it to evaluate to false, but when I step through the code it goes into both the `return true` and then goes into `return false`, but in the if statement that calls this code, it always seems to return true.

I don't understand what is wrong with this if statement, I've tried swapping over the two variables in the if statement but has made no luck.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: We know for sure that your return true and return false cannot be called in the same condition check. The only possible explanation is that the if statement is called twice, with different values for secondsBeforeLogoff and difference the second time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I debug and step through the code above the secondsBeforeLogOff is set to 60 and the difference is 5. ...  it always seems to return true.

That is correct, since 60 is greater than 5.

---

Also you can simply write:

```
return secondsBeforeLogOff > difference;
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, I did try it the other way round before, god knows what I did to make it not work. Probably the most stupidest question asked on here, thanks for your help

Comment: I think you're right: you are really tired. Consider taking a nap and coming back to this another time. :)

Answer (score 0):

The eclipse debugger always does this giving you a false impression over which condition was hit. :(